# Docker volume files not writable, written as root

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-volume

I own a folder, `/me/tmp` to which I mount a docker volume: `docker run -v /me/tmp/:/root/tmp/`.  However when my Docker container creates folder and files instead the directory, e.g. `/root/tmp/subdir/file.txt` that file is created as root, and with no write permissions for other groups or users.  This means that outside the container, I can't edit or even remove this file `/me/tmp/subdir/file.txt`.  Is there any way to change the permissions or owner of the file without root access, or any way to avoid this from the start?

Comment: This might help: https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/

Answer (score 1):

You could run docker with user mapping, so any file created with uid 0 (root in the container) is automatically mapped to another uid on the host.  This is handled by two files `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`.

Read the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)

Answer (score -3):

Try running `RUN chmod -R 777 /root/tmp/` or `RUN chmod 777 /root/tmp/` in your dockerfile, or go into the container and type `chmod -R 777 /root/tmp` or `chmod 777 /root/tmp` as root.  The `-R` is for recursive